# Get called method name without __call

Tags: php, reflection, stack-trace

Is there any way to get called method name, using reflection or anything else?

Suppose I have following class:

```
abstract class FooController {

    /**
     * Current language
     * @var string
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * Controller action called by framework
     * @return string
     */
    public function dosomethingAction()
    {
        $template = $this->getLocalizedTemplate();
        //do something

        return $template;
    }

    /**
     * Builds template name using current 
     * action name and $language value
     * @return string
     */
    private function getLocalizedTemplate()
    {
        $ACTION_NAME; //how to obtain it?
        $filteredActionName = preg_replace("/Action$/", "", $ACTION_NAME);
        return $filteredActionName . "_" . $this->language . '.phtml';
    }

}
```

Comment: `debug_backtrace()`. But that's not really a sane way to do things. The behaviour of your function **should not** depend on *who* called it. Explicitly pass information forward, don't trace backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, if you're that set on coding this way, try a [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and parse out the class that called it. I'm not going to demonstrate since this isn't what I would recommend.

Instead, what you should do is inject directly the data you need. You're still using a function so you're not violating any coding principles here.

```
public function dosomethingAction()
{
    $template = $this->getLocalizedTemplate('dosomethingAction');
    //do something

    return $template;
}

private function getLocalizedTemplate($action)
{
    $filteredActionName = preg_replace("/Action$/", "", $action);
    return $filteredActionName . "_" . $this->language . '.phtml';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Fortunately it turns out that framework I'm currently using has ability to get current action name from application context. Anyway (at least for me) this is an interesting problem, and not obvious way to solve it, other than direct injection.